# remove same information in my data

Tags: r

I tried to clean my data in R, my data looks like this

```
  CustomerNumber  Revenue
    Customer1       3
    Customer2       4
    Customer3       5
```

How can I remove all the "Customer" in "Customer1" and make it like this

```
    CustomerNumber  Revenue
        1              3
        2              4
        3              5
```

I tried to Google the answer, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably just replace the word "Customer" with an empty space using `gsub`. Assuming `df` as your `data.frame` you can try,

```
df$CustomerName <- gsub("Customer", "", df$CustomerNumber)
df
# CustomerNumber  Revenue
#    1              3
#    2              4
#    3              5
```